# What's the difference between `#include` and `@include` in `/etc/sudoers`

Tags: apt, sudo, 21.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm updating to Ubuntu 21.04 and `apt` wants to swap out my `sudoers` file with one where `#include` is replaced by `@include`. Is the old syntax deprecated? It's not something I seem to be able to google.

Comment: The only thing I can find is this [sudo changeset 12448:c422a5c8ea5d](https://marc.info/?l=sudo-commits&m=159000688202280&w=2) (also found in the source package's `NEWS` file) - it's not clear to me whether the new syntax is mandatory or just preferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @steeldriver's comment, which provides the answer.

The [commit comment](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/c422a5c8ea5d) states the reason for the new directive is to avoid confusion because `#` is also used for comments.

> Add support for @include and @includedir
> These are less confusing than #include and #includedir when the
> hash character is also the comment character.

The [latest man page](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers) indicates both directives are accepted, but the old style is supported for backwards compatibility. I infer the new style is preferred.  There is no indication the old style will stop being supported.

> It is possible to include other sudoers files from within the sudoers file currently being parsed using the @include and @includedir directives. For compatibility with sudo versions prior to 1.9.1, #include and #includedir are also accepted.